# NoMethodError: undefined method `type' for nil:NilClass uuid.rb:146:in `generate_uuids_if_needed'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, uuid

I'm working on a rails app that includes paperclip and a uuid for my database. Each user has_many uploads and each upload belongs to a user. The problem is, When appending an upload to a user, as it saves to the database I get this error:

```
 user = User.find(6)

pdf = Upload.new(:pdf => File.new("/home/orinamokaya/Desktop/ted/1.pdf","r"), :path => "haha") 
user.uploads << pdf

NoMethodError: undefined method `type' for nil:NilClass

from /home/orinamokaya/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/bundler/gems/activeuuid-d63f251f2bdf/lib/activeuuid/uuid.rb:146:in `generate_uuids_if_needed'
from /home/orinamokaya/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.1.1/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:424:in `block in make_lambda'
from /home/orinamokaya/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.1.1/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:160:in `call'
from /home/orinamokaya/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.1.1/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:160:in `block in halting'
from /home/orinamokaya/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.1.1/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:86:in `call'
from /home/orinamokaya/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.1.1/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:86:in `run_callbacks'
from /home/orinamokaya/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.1.1/lib/active_record/callbacks.rb:306:in `create_record'
from /home/orinamokaya/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.1.1/lib/active_record/timestamp.rb:57:in `create_record'
from /home/orinamokaya/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.1.1/lib/active_record/persistence.rb:482:in `create_or_update'
from /home/orinamokaya/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.1.1/lib/active_record/callbacks.rb:302:in `block in create_or_update'
from /home/orinamokaya/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.1.1/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:113:in `call'
from /home/orinamokaya/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.1.1/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:113:in `call'
from /home/orinamokaya/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.1.1/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:166:in `block in halting'
from /home/orinamokaya/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.1.1/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:215:in `call'
from /home/orinamokaya/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.1.1/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:215:in `block in halting_and_conditional'
```

My Upload model

```
class Upload < ActiveRecord::Base
 include ActiveUUID::UUID #adding uuid to the database using the activeuuid gem forked from github

belongs_to :user

validates :pdf, :attachment_presence => true
validates_with AttachmentPresenceValidator, :attributes => :pdf
has_attached_file :pdf, :styles => { :medium => "300x300>", :thumb => "100x100>" }, :default_url => "/images/:style/missing.png", :path => ":rails_root/public/system/users/pdf/:id/:style/:filename"
validates_attachment_content_type :pdf, :content_type => ["application/pdf"]


end
```

Answer (score 2):

Ensure that the column in the model which you are using ActiveUUID::UUID on is set to the primary key.

For me I hit this issue on my tickets.rb model, my schema.rb was missing primary_key: true on my t.uuid :id column.